# There is no editor available for a .bin file type? (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio, c++

I've successfully written to a binary file, but when I go to open it, it gives me the error in the title along with "Make sure the application for the file type (.bin) is installed. Doesn't VS already have .bin file types? I'm using C++ so I figured it would be common.

How do I go about "installing" this .bin file type.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. How did you write to the ".bin" file? Was it programmatically using C++, or using visual studio, or in some other way? And how are you trying to open the file, programmatically using C++ or directly in visual studio ("File" > "open"), or some other way? Note that ".bin" is a generic extension used by several applications and don't necessarily match the format that any specific program would expect.

Comment: I converted my text to binary, hence it going to a .bin file. And yes, I did do File > Open, and .bin is a generic extension, but some other VS 2017's was able to open the binary file even though I couldn't. I downloaded 2019 though, so we're good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug that was [fixed.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67086/binary-editor-missing-for-open-with-in-vs-2017-1.html)

If you're on the latest version and it still isn't there you may need to [manually install it.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15286/cant-find-binary-editor.html)

> you can install the Visual C++ Core Features component (from the Individual Components tab in the VS Installer) and it should get you the binary editor. It's was around 75MB for me instead of installing the full C++ workload (which is a few GB).

You can solve this problem by installing updating your installation of [Visual Studio 2017 to 15.9.4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes).  This particular problem was fixed with [Visual Studio 2017 15.5.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.5) back in December 2017.

Comment: Oh man, if I download the new update, will I be able to access the same code from the older version? I'm using 2017 and that version is 2019.

Comment: @AngoMango - The bug was reported against Visual Studio 2017 over 20 months ago.  The bug was patched against Visual Studio 2017.  *All you need to do is run the Visual Studio 2017 Updater.*